# Under PPSWOR of size $2$ or $3$, inclusion probability of $i$th unit exceeds that of $j$th unit when $i$th unit has largr size measure than $j$th unit

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

I was reading PPSWOR (Probability Proportional to Size and WithOut Replacement) sampling and this question suddenly struck me

> Is it true that under PPSWOR of size $2$ or $3$, inclusion probability of $i$th unit exceeds that of $j$th unit whenever $i$th unit has a larger size measure than $j$th unit?

I can't decide for sure whether it's true or not. All I could think of are-

> Selection probability of unit $i$ is
> $$p_i=\frac{x_i}{\sum x_i}$$
> Since we have a PPSWOR distribution, it remains the same in each draw.
>
> Probability of selecting unit $i$ and $j$ is $p_i\cdot p_j$.
>
> So, possible samples are $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$ and $(2,3)$.

But, I can't proceed any more than this. Can anyone please help?

Also, is there any $n>3$ for which PPSWOR of size $n$ satisfies the given condition?

Also, I am not sure about the tags. Feel free to edit them.

Comment: As someone with a reputation of $1500+$, I would assume you know that we don't post isolated questions here.

Comment: @learning123 I just started on this topic. So, I thought, my work won't be of any help. But still, I'm placing an edit with my work. Give me a minute.

Comment: @learning123 Okay now?

Comment: I don't have any expertise in what you are talking about... but seems fine to me! ☺️

Comment: I would have thought the denominator of $p_i=\frac{x_i}{\sum x_i}$ changes with successive samples without replacement, so it does not remain the same in each draw.  But having higher probability items being more likely to be sampled overall than lower probability items seems obviously true, even if they might be less likely to be sampled later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having larger items being more likely to be sampled overall than smaller  items seems obviously true. Here is a demonstration for a sample of size $2$ without replacement, where the weights are $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$ with finite $s=\sum x_i$.

The probability of selecting item $1$ in a sample of size $2$ without replacement is $$p_1= \frac{x_1}{s} + \frac{x_2}{s} \frac{x_1}{s-x_2} + \sum\limits_{k\ge 3} \frac{x_k}{s} \frac{x_1}{s-x_k}= \frac{x_1}{s-x_2}  +x_1 \sum\limits_{k\ge 3} \frac{x_k}{s(s-x_k)}$$

The probability of selecting item $2$  in a sample of size $2$ without replacement is  $$p_2=\frac{x_2}{s} + \frac{x_1}{s} \frac{x_2}{s-x_1} + \sum\limits_{k\ge 3} \frac{x_k}{s} \frac{x_2}{s-x_k}= \frac{x_2}{s-x_1}  +x_2 \sum\limits_{k\ge 3} \frac{x_k}{s(s-x_k)}$$

If $x_1>x_2$ and $s>x_1+x_2$ then

- $\frac{x_1}{s-x_2}>\frac{x_2}{s-x_1}$ since their difference is $(x_1-x_2) \frac{s-x_1-x_2}{(s-x_1)(s-x_2)}$
- $x_1 \sum\limits_{k\ge 3} \frac{x_k}{s(s-x_k)} > x_2 \sum\limits_{k\ge 3} \frac{x_k}{s(s-x_k)}$

so $p_1>p_2$ as expected.  You could do something more complicated for larger samples without replacement.

This does not mean that item $1$ is more likely to be selected than item $2$ in the second round of sampling.  For example with weights $x_1=90, x_2=9, x_3=1$, you get

- the probability of item $1$ being selected in the first round being $0.9$ and being selected in the second round about $0.0981$ for a total of about  $0.9981$,
- the probability of item $2$ being selected in the first round being $0.09$ and being selected in the second round about $0.8109$ for a total of about  $0.9009$,
- the probability of item $3$ being selected in the first round being $0.01$ and being selected in the second round about $0.0910$ for a total of about  $0.1010$.

Comment: That's a nice solution! Thanks!